# How do Dominate Person and Confusion interact?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

Consider a three-way battle between Alice, Bob, and Carol. Alice casts [Confusion](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/confusion/) on Carol, and Carol fails her save. Bob casts [Dominate Person](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dominate-person/) on Carol, who again fails her save, and orders her to attack Alice.

What happens on Carol's turn?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/127364/if-you-command-grovel-a-creature-that-is-already-under-the-effect-of-confusi?rq=1

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 That question is about 5e, so not really?

Comment: Have to admit I missed the tag in the old question, but after reading David Coffron's answer and checking the Core Rulebook it appears to apply equally to Pathfinder.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 It is important to note that a question is not a duplicate just because the answer is the same. Any number of systems could have different interaction results between similar effects. That is why system tags exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the rules for [overlapping enchantment effects](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Combining-Magic-Effects), (emphasis added)

> Sometimes magical effects that establish mental control **render each other irrelevant, such as spells that remove the subject’s ability to act. Mental controls that don’t remove the recipient’s ability to act usually do not interfere with each other.** If a creature is under the mental control of two or more creatures, it tends to obey each to the best of its ability, and to the extent of the control each effect allows. If the controlled creature receives conflicting orders simultaneously, the competing controllers must make opposed Charisma checks to determine which one the creature obeys.

... both spells are still effective. The affected creature, here Carol, will first roll for Confusion, then do what Bob wills on a 01-25.

Answer (score 2):

## Dominate Person wins.

Consider the spell descriptions.

### Confusion

> This spell causes confusion in the targets, making them unable to determine **their actions.**

### Dominate Person

> You can **control the actions** of any humanoid creature through a telepathic link that you establish with the subject’s mind.

Even though a confused creature is unable to determine what to do, they don't get to. Whoever has cast Dominate Person gets to choose that through the link.